# Undefined reference to `ulocdata_open_63'

Tags: unicode, icu

I am using ICU lib for Exemplar, I am getting undefined ref for `ulocdata_open_63'
I am not using "ulocdata_open_63" function but "ulocdata_open". Library is linked properly.

Why it is looking for ulocdata_open_63 definition even though I am not calling it.

```
Sample code:-

#include <stdio.h>
#define UNICODE 
#include <unicode/uloc.h>
#include <unicode/ulocdata.h>
#include <unicode/urename.h>

typedef unsigned short U16;

int main()
{
char localeID[ULOC_FULLNAME_CAPACITY+ULOC_KEYWORD_AND_VALUES_CAPACITY] = "en_US";
UErrorCode icuStatus = U_ZERO_ERROR;
ULocaleData* uld = ulocdata_open("en", &icuStatus);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you're linking against a ICU library that was built with ICU version suffixes, which is the default. To build a library without version suffixes you'll have to add the flag `--disable-renaming` to the configure build step of ICU4C.

See https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu4c/build.html#icu-as-a-system-level-library.